# Postgress error- bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku-postgres

When I run

```
$bundle install
```

I am running the project on heroku so I had to switch to postgress. I keep getting this error for some reason.

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.15.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that gem install pg -v '0.15.1' succeeds before bundling.
```

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'



gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: Can you give me a gist of the results of running "gem install pg -v '0.15.1'"?

Comment: sometimes it happens due to slow net connection also.

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Gemfile it seems that you are using sqlite3 for development and postgres for production. You don't have to install postgres locally. Just do bundle install without production group:

```
bundle install --without production
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the version in the gem file:
gem 'pg'
only...

Answer (score 0):

Try bundle install --without development test postgresql